# Encryption-Decryption in APIGEE

Tags: encryption, apigee

When we get an encrypted request to our APIGEE API Proxy ,and we want APIGEE proxy  to decrypt it before letting it to reach backend,should I have to think about SSL so that Encryption-Decryption happens through keys in certificates for such requirement?
**Or** We have to randomly create keys as we get AESEncryptionDecryption java programs and use Javacallout in APIGEE policy?
**Or** is there any other better design solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should rely on SSL/TLS to encrypt and decrypt the payloads. You should not consider doing your own encryption via callout unless there is a very well reasoned argument to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot PaulProgrammer.That  answers my question!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the incoming traffic (Northbound, the public end-point) is secured with SSL/TLS (HTTPS).
That means that the Apigee platform will handle all SSL/TLS related encryption.

If your Southbound (back-end API) is HTTP (to SSL/TLS), the HTTP connection is also handled by Apigee.

This is just your basic API proxy. No Java required.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for the request encryption SSL/TLS is the recommended way to rely on, but if a service callout is made from Apigee proxy then it doesn't use SSL unless truststore is explicitly mentioned. It is a bug that is detected very recently.